# Install python library on elasticbeanstalk which requires sudo

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, boto, boto3

I'm trying to install boto3 for my django project deployed with aws elastic-beanstalk. The library requires that I run as sudo and therefore gives me a permission denied error.

I'm just putting the boto3==1.2.1 in my requirement.txt file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I forgot the double = signs. No need for sudo.

Comment: The deploy script is run by root.